# Unable to extract item with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use beautiful soup to return the number of datasets there are on this website.

However, I'm not sure what is wrong with my code.

I can't seem to extract just the number of datasets. (datasets is 3908)

```
base_url = www.quandl.com/data/TSE
web_content = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(base_url).text, "html.parser")
for stats in web_content.findAll('table', attrs={'class'}):
     print(stats)
```

How should i structure my code?

Comment: It looks like this website has a free API that you can use which offers unlimited use.  Not only will this be easier for you, but I'm sure they would also prefer you use the API rather than scraping their page directly.

Comment: Yes, they do have a free API. But this API doesn't give me the dataset number. It does a lot of other things but that.. I'm looking to just get the total number of datasets. which is 3908

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
attrs={'class' : ''}
```

So you have:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
base_url = 'http://www.quandl.com/data/TSE'
web_content = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(base_url).text, "html.parser")
for stats in web_content.findAll('table', attrs={'class' : ''}):
     print(stats)
```

Note: If your target supports javascript, `requests` is not a good idea, You can Try PhantomJS instead.

Edit:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
base_url = 'http://www.quandl.com/data/TSE'
web_content = requests.get(base_url).text
tree = html.fromstring(web_content)
print tree.xpath('//tr/td/text()')[3]
```

Comment: thanks for this, but I was wondering, would it be possible to just get the number 3908? Currently, it gives me everything in the tables. I'm just trying to return this value..

Comment: Wow. this works. Does lxml do a better / easier job than beautiful soup?

Comment: We have some extractors like `beautiful soup` and `xpath`. I am good with xpath.I think this is better. but it depends on you...

Comment: Hey, I was trying to recreate your code with `xpath` that I copied directly from the website (same link as my initial qns). This was the `xpath` that I copied `//*[@id="ember667"]/div[2]/main/section/section/section[2]/div[3]/div[2]/span[2]`. It is the `xpath` to the value `3908` that i'm looking for. Why is it that I cant paste it into your code and have it work??